# inserting same query from multiple array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I make a mathematichs function in mysql. and give two result because it`s calculate from 2 records. this is the source :

```
$calculate= mysql_query("select markers_tujuan.lng,markers_tujuan.lat,open_list.lat, open_list.lng,
((SQRT((((markers_tujuan.lat-markers_tujuan.lng)*(markers_tujuan.lat-markers_tujuan.lng)) + ((open_list.lat-open_list.lng)*(open_list.lat-open_list.lng)))))+(sqrt((((markers_tujuan.lat-open_list.lat)*((markers_tujuan.lat-open_list.lat)))+((markers_tujuan.lng-open_list.lng)*((markers_tujuan.lng-open_list.lng))))))) 
as hasil
from markers_tujuan, open_list");

$op=mysql_query("select * from open_list");
$line=mysql_fetch_assoc($op);


/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($calculate)) {
    printf ("1(%s %s),(%s %s),%s <br> \n", $row["lng"], $row["lat"], $row["lat"], $row["lng"], $row["hasil"]);
        $try=mysql_query(" UPDATE open_list SET hitung = '".$row["hasil"]."' ");
    }
```

and the result is
[image: php running]

but I didn`t understand why query in mysql updating same query

[image: error query]

Comment: you need a where condition to tell which row to update ?

Comment: you dont have WHERE in update statement,so it updates every row.

Comment: can anybody tell me the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your UPDATE statement does not have a WHERE condition. Therefore, every single row in your table will be updated, each time:

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE open_list SET hitung = '".$row["hasil"]."' ");
```

You should specify the PRIMARY KEY while updating. In this case, it is the column `id` (I presume). Example:

```
UPDATE open_list SET hitung = 'example' WHERE id = '4'
```

Comment: Add `open_list.id` in the field list for your SELECT query. Then try using: `mysql_query(" UPDATE open_list SET hitung = '".$row["hasil"]."' WHERE id = '" . $row['id'] . "'");`

Comment: I 've been try it but get en error :  Undefined index: id in $try=mysql_query(" UPDATE open_list SET hitung = '".$row["hasil"]."' WHERE id = '" . $row['id'] . "'");

Comment: @hot_programmer You didn't add `open_list.id` to your field list in the SELECT query.

Comment: something like this right ? $op=mysql_query("select open_list.id from open_list"); . I did it and get that error message

Comment: No, you will need to add it to the first query in your code above.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `SELECT open_list.id,...` on your first query and `WHERE id = ' . $row['id']` in the update sentence.